# Laravel: math in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

In SQL it's fairly trivial to do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM properties WHERE (price / acres) = 3000;
```

This would select every property where the "price per acre" is 3000

I wish to do this in Laravel. I tried the following:

```
Property::where('price / acres', 3000)->get();
```

However this wrapped the column title in backticks, creating the following SQL:

```
select * from `properties` where `price / acres` = 3000
```

This failed (obviously) with the error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price / acres' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw) like this:

```
Property::whereRaw('(price / acres) = 3000')->get();
```

Comment: ah okay this is probably a better way now that I think about it!

Comment: Not as elegant as I'd like since I'm now having to clean and escape user inputs, but it worked

Comment: If you need to pass a number as a variable, change the 3000 to a ?, and pass it instead. `Property::whereRaw('(price / acres) = ?',[$yourvariable])->get();` This can't be done with column names.

Answer (score 1):

you're right you can't attribute where statements that way in Laravel. One option you always have is to submit a raw SQL statement using the DB Facade - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries

For example:

```
$price_per_acre = DB::select('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE (price / acres) = 3000');
```